# How to set the positioning of the caret in my ion-input with Ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

The caret is too much to the left of the inputbox and it looks horrible.

[image: Username Ion-Input]

Comment: Please provide your CSS/HTML.  There's not much anyone can do to help with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this CSS to the ion-input

```css
--padding-start: 25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Place icons inside input like this:
user Slot attribute to position your icon inside your input.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="stacked">Stacked Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
  <ion-icon name="lock" slot="end"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```